# Why is the index of an object in a two-dimensional array returning -1?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this method:

```
public static int[][] executeRules(int[][] array){
    int rowNumber = 0;
    for(int[] row : array){

        for (int cell:row){
            int index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(cell);
            System.out.println(index);
            int[] surroundingCells = getSurroundingCells(index);

            int liveCells = 0;
            for(int aSurroundingCell: surroundingCells){
                if(aSurroundingCell == 1){
                    liveCells++;
                }
            }

            //If cell is dead
            if (cell == 0){


                //Bring cell back to life if condition is met (three surrounding cells alive)
                if (liveCells == 3){

                    cell = 1;
                    liveCells = 0;
                }


            }
            //If cell is alive
            else if (cell == 1){
                //If cell is underpopulated
                if (liveCells < 2){
                    cell = 0;
                }
                if (liveCells > 3){
                    cell = 1;
                }




            }else {
                System.out.println("An error has occured.");

            }

            if(index != -1){
                array [rowNumber][index] = cell;
            }
        }
        if(rowNumber < _size - 1){
            rowNumber ++;
        }

    }
    return array;
}
```

It is conway's game of life, yes. I'm trying to test every "cell" in this two dimensional array, then change its value and then return the new array. But for some reason the index of the second dimension is returning -1 all the time. I have no idea why. Does anyone know?

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 if the value is not found.

Comment: It's kind of silly to use `indexOf` in this situation vs just doing a conventional `for` loop.

Comment: what yout got in your `List` there is `array`'s and not the values, since you pased a `int [][]` you have a list of `int[]`

Comment: Yep, that `indexOf` doesn't have a ghost of a chance of working.

Comment: @DimaMaligin found the issue, `Arrays.asList(array)` should be changed to `Arrays.asList(row)` - you should publish it as an answer!

Comment: @alfasin then you will only get a 1 dimensional index. I assume the OP wanted 2dim index from the original `int[][]`.

Comment: If you change `for(int[] row : array)` to `for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++)` and pass `array[i]` to the `indexOf` you can use `i` as the second index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int[] row : array){
    for (int cell:row){
        int index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(cell);
```

You're getting a little confused between your rows and cells. `array` is an array of arrays, so `indexOf()` will be searching for array values (rows), but the `cell` value you pass in is just an `int`. It can never find an `int` that's equal to an `int[]`.

It's sort of convoluted and inefficient to use a for-each loop and then try to find the index by scanning for the value inside your loop. When working with array indexes, I strongly recommend using traditional `for` loops instead of for-each loops.

```
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < array.length; rowIndex++) {
    int[] row = array[rowIndex];
    for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.length; columnIndex++) {
       int[] surroundingCells = getSurroundingCells(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

Also, be aware that the way Java treats memory references, setting a variable's value will *only* change that variable. You must use the array's index-setting syntax to actually change the value at a given point in the array:

```
       int cell = array[rowIndex][columnIndex];
       cell = someValue; // This does nothing to your array values.
       array[rowIndex][columnIndex] = someValue; // This is what you want.
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `indexOf` specify that it returns

> the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this
>   list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

Which mean that the list does not contain the element.

The problem in your code is that `asList` is called but does not do what you think.

The `asList` method will return a `List<int[]>` but you are searching in the `List` for index of an int (cell), which will never be found.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).

Comment: @Squid  
what yout got in your `List `there is `array`'s and not the values, since you pased a `int [][]` you have a list of `int[]`

Comment: @alfasin Edited to give more details.